# C# MVC3 Passing Array in Object to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm wondering why my controller is not recognizing an array of ints but recognizes an object literal of ints.

c#:
Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(Model search)
```

Model:

```
public class Model {
    public int[] MyList {get; set;}
}
```

javascript:

```
model.myList = [0, 1]; //null at controller
model.myList = {0, 1}; //controller recognizes this
```

What's going on here?

Comment: I guess you must need to send data to controller as an object to controller. It will not recognize string. Please check the [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help for information with regards to how MVC translates and treats arrays, dictionary objects etc http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by changing `[HttpGet]` to `[HttPost]`